# Find out netplan duid before starting the system

Tags: 18.04, netplan, lxd, cloud-init

is there a way to find out the duid netplan is using to request the dhcp lease before starting the system. Can it be calculated or triggered from outside?

Use case:
Before netplan, I used the following workflow for creating lxd containers (e.g. Ubuntu 16.04, -> isc dhcpd):

- init container (`lxc init ubuntu:x foo`)
- read mac address from lxd config (`lxc config show foo`)
- at the dhcp servers create a reservation
- start container (`lxc start foo`)
- happy :)

I need an IP address at first startup of the container/machine, because I automated the configuration of some agents which need attributes from the dhcp setup. Thats done by cloud-init in the lxd profiles.

Things are not always getting better :/
How could they default to duid when it is not readable in advance?

Another point is the setup of bare metal machines. For an automated deployment of the OS you have an additional step "go to the server attach kvm and get the duid". Further in pxe boot and os, the system have different ip addresses. Thats a step backwards in my opinion. Is netplan really the right choice for servers?

Best
Christian

Answer (score 0):

LXD in its default configuration configures dnsmasq to provide the duid..

Path assumes the snap installed LXD.
cd /var/snap/lxd/common/lxd/networks/lxdbrd

```
grep duid dnsmasq.leases
duid 00:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:1d:d0:ac:1f:6b:da:22:08
```